# So and neither, me too, me neither, etc. What are all possible options?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Are all the answers correct?

**My grandchildren speak English.** — So do ours. / Ours do too. / Ours too.

**I hate cooking.** — So do I./ I do too. / Me too.

**My son doesn’t smoke.** — Neither does mine. / My son (doesn’t smoke) either./ Mine doesn't / Mine neither.

**My dad isn’t interested in politics.** — Neither is mine. /Mine isn't either. / My (isn't interested in politics) either / Mine neither

**I am crazy about cabbage.** — So am I./ I am too./ Me too.

**Your son should learn how to act in polite society.** — So should yours. / Yours should too. / Yours too.

**I will be sleeping all day tomorrow.** — So will I./ I will too./ Me too.

**I can’t dance.** — Neither can I. / I can't (dance) either. / Me neither.

**I haven’t done my homework yet.** — Neither have I. / I haven't (done my homework) either. / Me neither.

Have I missed something? Or maybe I was wrong in some of the examples?

Answer (score 1):

All but three of the answers look idiomatic:

**In the third set**,

> My son doesn’t smoke. — Neither does mine. / <del>My son (doesn’t smoke) either</del>./ <del>Mine doesn't</del> / Mine neither.

The answer "My son (doesn't smoke) either." is incorrect without "doesn't", because it lacks the negation.

The answer "Mine doesn't" would be used for contrast with someone who said "My son smokes.", not to say that your son also doesn't smoke.

**In the fourth set,**

> My dad isn’t interested in politics. — Neither is mine. /Mine isn't either. / <del>My (isn't interested in politics) either</del> / Mine neither

The answer "my (isn't interested in politics) either" is not correct usage. It should be "mine", which is a pronoun. "My" is only an adjective and doesn't work there.